# Rails 4 find_or_create_by_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, associations

I have a association one to many between users and university with auto-complete feature where  users can chose the university if founded else they create a new university but the create method doesn't work

this is my user model

```
  def university_name
    university.try(:name)
  end

  def university_name=(name)
    self.university = University.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

this is my user form view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :university_name, "Nom de l'université", class: "nom-universite" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :university_name, data: {autocomplete_source: University.order(:name).map(&:name) }, class: "form-control form-newuniver" %>
</div>
```

i have also this code in the user profile show view

```
  <p>
    <strong>Université:</strong>
       <%= @user.university_name %>
  </p>
```

and this is my autocomplete Jquery code

```
jQuery ->
  $('#user_university_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#user_university_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it is a strong parameter problem

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
  def university_name=(name)
    self.university = University.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

use `University` i.e., model name instead of `university`.

Also, in Rails4 you could just use:

```
University.find_or_create_by(name: name)
```

In order to access the above mentioned method:

For eg: for a user

```
@user.university_name= "Stanford"
```

Comment: How are you calling the method? It should be called on an instance of user. For eg: @user.university_name = "Stanford"

Comment: I had a typo in comment example. Fixed it. See the above comment.

Comment: <p>
            <strong>university:</strong>
               <%= @user.university_name  %>
          </p>

Comment: You are accessing the value i.e. calling first method(getter) not the second(setter). You need something like `@user.university_name= "Stanford"`, this will call  `university_name=(name)` method.

Comment: non and now even the autocomplete feature don't work, if i chose a university that is in the list it doesn't appear in the show page i don't know why

Comment: The code that you shared doesn't give any idea of views or models etc. It would be great if you could have shared that. This answer will only resolve the specific `find_or_create` issue. Also, its not good to modify the question with the given answer. Please post another question for the current issue.